# Manual Implementation of Sobel Operator in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to apply a sobel operator by iterating through an image and applying a mask to surrounding pixels.

For now, I am trying to apply the vertical portion of the mask, which is:

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

In my implementaiton, I am iterating through the rows and columns as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < image.rows-1; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < image.cols-1; j++){
            int pixel1 = image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j-1)[0] * -1;
            int pixel2 = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[0] * 0;
            int pixel3 = image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[0] * 1;

            int pixel4 = image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[0] * -2;
            int pixel5 = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] * 0;
            int pixel6 = image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[0] * 2;

            int pixel7 = image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[0] * -1;
            int pixel8 = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[0] * 0;
            int pixel9 = image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[0] * 1;

            int sum = pixel1 + pixel2 + pixel3 + pixel4 + pixel5 + pixel6 + pixel7 + pixel8 + pixel9;
            verticalSobel.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = sum;
            verticalSobel.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = sum;
            verticalSobel.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = sum;
        }
    }
```

Where the pixels are labeled as:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

However, the resulting image is far off of what it should look like.

For reference, the resulting image is [image]

Where it should look similar to: 
[image]

The guide I am using is: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/sobel_operator.htm

I am not sure if I am simply implementing the operator incorrectly, or just iterating through the image incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have problems where the sum is negative. Take the absolute value of `sum`, and clamp it to 255 (or instead of absolute value, clamp it to 0 - depending of what you want to achieve. A "full" sobel operator usually uses 2d distance formula, so a horizonal/vertical only variant should use the absolute value)

Comment: Perfect! Using abs(sum) when setting my pixel value fixed it. I'm just curious as to what you mean by clamping the value. Are you saying if the value is > 255, then set it to 255?

Comment: @ecatalano: yes, as `sum` can be larger than 255

Comment: you can use opencv's saturate_cast function to prevent over- and underflows.